# some part of css is not applying to my Next.Js project after deploying vercel

Tags: next.js, deployment, fetch-api, vercel

In this video showing the website on localhost => development mode.

Here is everything is ok but some important css is not applied to my vercel app. I don't understand why it's happening.

this is deployed link=> https://mitnog.vercel.app/

Note: I don't add vercel.json file and I am useing Tailwind css. In the first Comment I will set the tailwind css sc  and folder structure.

[Tailwind css and folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X0Qt.png)

how can i apply all the css to my vercel project.

Q-2
**Note:**
I am using fetch api.node.js use for backend and also deployed to vercel. in this case my data is not loading properly. data loaded first time but after some data is gone and come again ......

what should be solution for this issue?